# Get imagelist image to Clipboard

Tags: c#, vb.net, clipboard, picturebox, imagelist

I need to get image in to Imagelist to windows clipboard. I don't want to save that image in the computer. I found lots of article and post that explaining how to set image to Picturebox from clipboard. But I need the opposite direction.

Is there any code support for vb.net or C#?

Comment: [Clipboard.SetImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setimage.aspx) ?

Comment: Please give me an example. I'm new to C#. Thanks

Comment: What difficulties do you have? Can you get `Image`? Do you use [tag:winforms] or [tag:wpf]?

Comment: I use winforms. I don't know how to start

Comment: I was stupid to ask that, because `PictureBox` is [tag:winforms], sorry =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
Clipboard.SetImage(pictureBox.Image);
```

If you have `ImageList`, then

```
Clipboard.SetImage(imageList.Images[index]);
```

Comment: Ill try I let you know. Thanks